# Exponential power of 2

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to work on VHDL code which needs to find exponential power of 2. For example: T_1 <= 8191 + 2**DATA_3; where DATA_3 is a variable.I have included "use IEEE.MATH_REAL.ALL;" in the header. However, this is not working. Can somebody give me some suggestions?

Comment: What is the range of valid values for DATA_3?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to compute powers of 2, it is better to simply shift left your vector.

In VHDL, the code in your case will have the following format :

```
T_1 <= 8191 + (1 sll DATA_3);
```

Avoid using real function because they are often not synthesizable (Except is you have a coprocessor IP in your FPGA).

Comment: sll is not defined for type integer.   perhaps you could re-write your expression in type unsigned and then convert it to an integer.

Comment: Good idea, but again it depends on what type is DATA_3 also ?

Comment: DATA_3 is an integer. Will I be able to execute the above said statement with DATA_3 as in integer? Or do I have to write some extra lines of codes?

Comment: How do I write a code for unsigned and then covert it into an integer?

Comment: When I tried using the above mentioned line of code, I got an error "sll can not have such operands in this context."

Comment: What is the type of your T_1 signal ? (Please always elaborate your question with the types you are using :) )

Comment: Actually, There is no way what I've done works. Everything is INTEGER, and I assign it to a signal without conversion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192374/discussion-between-ayoub-bargach-and-vishvachi-sinha).

Answer (score 0):

[Compute exp(x) using VHDL](https://surf-vhdl.com/compute-exp-x-fpga-using-vhdl/)

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity exp_lut is
port(
  i_clk          : in  std_logic;
  i_rstb         : in  std_logic;
  i_x            : in  std_logic_vector( 3 downto 0);
  o_exp          : out std_logic_vector( 7 downto 0));
end exp_lut;

architecture rtl of exp_lut is
constant C_LUT_DEPTH    : integer := 4;  -- 16 word
constant C_LUT_BIT      : integer := 8;     -- 8 bit LUT

type t_lut_exp is array(0 to (2**C_LUT_DEPTH)-1) of integer range 0 to (2**C_LUT_BIT)-1;

constant C_LUT_ADDR_OFFSET         : unsigned(C_LUT_DEPTH-1 downto 0):= to_unsigned(2**(C_LUT_DEPTH-1),C_LUT_DEPTH);

signal lut_addr                    : unsigned(C_LUT_DEPTH-1 downto 0);
signal lut_value                   : std_logic_vector(C_LUT_BIT-1 downto 0);

constant C_LUT_EXP : t_lut_exp :=(
   39,
   44,
   50,
   57,
   64,
   73,
   83,
   94,
  106,
  120,
  136,
  155,
  175,
  199,
  225,
  255);

begin

p_rom : process(i_clk)
begin
  if(rising_edge(i_clk)) then
    lut_addr   <= C_LUT_ADDR_OFFSET + unsigned(i_x);
    lut_value  <= std_logic_vector(to_signed(C_LUT_EXP(to_integer(lut_addr)),C_LUT_BIT));
  end if;
end process p_rom;

p_exp : process(i_clk,i_rstb)
begin
  if(i_rstb='0') then
    o_exp     <= (others=>'0');
  elsif(rising_edge(i_clk)) then
    o_exp     <= lut_value;
  end if;
end process p_exp;

end rtl;
```

Comment: not needed overkill...